# Add JSF-Tomahawk library to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomahawk

I've been trying to add tomahawk library to a JSF app.
I click on project -> BuildPath -> Libraries -> Add external Jars.
But when I try to deploy there's a message that says that there's no taglib for **t**.

So, what's the correct way of adding a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of adding webapp-specific libraries is just dropping the JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib`. That's all. Eclipse is smart enough to detect changes in the `/WEB-INF/lib` and will take appropriate actions automagically. You really don't need to fiddle with Build Path in project's properties. It would possibly make things worse. Undo all changes which you made in the Build Path.

Answer (score 0):

Are the libraries also part of your web-inf/lib ?